# Problem regarding the Connection string in connection statement while exporting to executable

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc

I have an application which has a database. the location of SQLite is in my source folder and while I had defined the string but when I exported into an executable and ran on another system the database is not loading

I had tried to place the database file into the source folder but it was not loading, though it was loading in source computer but not loading in another computer where I am executing it

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class jac {
    Connection conn=null;
    public static Connection dbConnector()
    {
        try {
         Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
         Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\saira\\eclipse-workspace\\hancer.zip_expanded\\ed\\src\\ed\\Material.sqlite");
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected");
            return conn;

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

I want to define the location of the database into the project so that when I create an executable the database could load in all other computers. which is I want to define the connection string so that it always refers in the project memory

Comment: You have a hardcoded absolute path in your connection string. Does that path exist on the other system?

Comment: No, it is not available in other system

Comment: Well, there is your problem. You either need to use some relative path, or make the path configurable, or do something else to infer the correct path.

Comment: But I want that database as an library in my application just like images so that it sits with the application when redistributed to other systems

Comment: Then you need to deploy that database as a separate file and use a relative path, or provide a mechanism to extract it to a temporary location or application config path and use it from there. Things like this don't happen automagically: your code will need to take care of it.

Comment: Any examples pls

Comment: Sorry, that is far too broad.

Comment: Tried various methods such as defining the file path doesn’t work thought